# Customization of the paypal checkout pop-up window

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a business logo but I can only see it when I change the payment pop-up window to full screen from its default size. Is there any way to make the pop-up full screen or to replace the PayPal logo with the business logo?

Default window image:
[default window size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxonN.png)

Expanded window image(Business name visible):
[bigger window w/ business name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv1TV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer small popup approval flow behaves the way it does by design.

When redirecting away from your site, the old redirect flow's use of that optional logo offered useful context so a payer could know who they were paying on the full page PayPal page.

Sine the new popup does not redirect away but rather leaves your site loaded in its background and is overlayed on top of it, that background gives the necessary context of who the payer is paying, and displaying a logo within the small popup would be redundant.

(The only thing that can be changed/customized within the pop up window is the business name.)

Comment: Thanks. But I am having the same issue with the business name. Is that normal as well? I updated the question with images.

Comment: It is normal for it to not be displayed as a header, yes. Again, your site in the background is there for this context.